# How to get all columns

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a problem in the model, how to get all the columns in the following select query:

```
public function getAllProvince($where = array())
{
    $this->db->select("id, name");
    $this->db->from('target_statis');
    $this->db->where($where); 
    $this->db->group_by("id, name"); 
    $this->db->order_by("id"); 
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0){  
        return $query->result(); 
    } 
    return false;
}
```

Comment: What is the issue you are facing?

Comment: Use `$this->db->select("*");` will select all columns..!

Answer (score 0):

**Try This,**

```
public function getAllProvince($where = array()){
        $this->db->select("*");//changed line
        $this->db->from('target_statis');
        $this->db->where($where); 
        $this->db->group_by("id,name"); 
        $this->db->order_by("id"); 
        $query = $this->db->get();
        if ($query->num_rows() >0){  
            return $query->result(); 
        }else{ 
            return array();//changed line
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm deleting `$this->db->select(column)` because you want to get all columns

If you not defining `$this->db->select()`, codeigniter will default select all the columns

also, I'm deleting `$this->db->from()` and move the table name to `$this->db->get('target_statis');`

```
public function getAllProvince($where = array()){
    $this->db->where($where); 
    $this->db->group_by("id,name"); 
    $this->db->order_by("id"); 
    $query = $this->db->get('target_statis'); 
    if ($query->num_rows() >0){  
        return $query->result(); 
    } 
    return FALSE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code...

```
 public function getAllProvince($where = array())
    {
        $this->db->select("*");
        $this->db->from('target_statis');
        $this->db->where($where); 
        $this->db->group_by("id, name"); 
        $this->db->order_by("id"); 
        $query = $this->db->get();
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0){  
            return $query->result(); 
        } 
        return false;
    }
```